# How to change the background image of the tab on runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

This is the most complicated part for me.
I have tabs in a page. Each tab has a background image of fixed length. So when the text for the tab is bigger("arrangement help"), it displays "arrangement" in one line and "help" underneath. My goal is to display arrangement and help in one line. Tabs have to customizable.I am using css for regular tabs.

```
#tabs a {
float:left;
background:url("../images/selection_deselect_bg.jpg") no-repeat right top;
margin:0;
text-decoration:none;
width:105px;
text-align:center;
height:24px;
font-size:12px;
color:#00779c;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
```

}.

In the aspx page, tabs are defined like this

```
 <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <span id="Tab1" runat="server">
                    <li id="li1"><a <%=strpage1anchor%> <%=page1display%>><span style="text">
                        <asp:Literal ID="litPage1" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span></a></li>
                </span>
```

I have an bigger image and i am able to get the size of the text in tab. But how to use bigger image for the tab? How to use change background on runtime. Please help me out!! Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 0):

`white-space:nowrap` will fix your wrap problem.

Changing the width of your fixed-width tabs at runtime seems a bit silly to me.  Maybe what you're looking for is the `min-width` style.

Keep in mind that your background image cannot be stretched or scaled in most browsers.

Comment: If you dont mind, can you tell me little more about min-width style? how can it be used here and how can it affect the width?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make (part of) your background image repeatable. If you can do that, it's the easiest way.

Otherwise, you'd probably have to use JS on load to compare the width of the tab with the image's width, and then act accordingly. That's a lot of trouble for cosmetics though IMHO.

Comment: How do i do that? Little more of explanation is needed. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Something like this: http://icant.co.uk/articles/flexible-css-menu/ or this: http://www.coremediadesign.co.uk/learn_web_design/free_web_design_tutorials/tutorial/css_tabbed_navigation_resize_bar.html